# UIImageView is not updating

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

Hi  iam using following code for loading image to uiimageview  its working when i loading that UIviewcontroller but if i open any other uiviewcontroller from the existing one and came back to the old uiviewcontroller and if i click a thumnail image  its not  not updating UIimageview uiviewcontroller.

img contains image path (inside device)
in viewdidload

```
[self setBookimage:img];
```

in setBookimage()

```
- (void)setBookImage:(UIImage *)bookImage{

    book_cover_image.image=nil;
    book_cover_image.image = bookImage;
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [book_cover_image.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

Thumbnail didselect methode code

```
   - (void)thumbnailListView:(ThumbnailListView*)thumbnailListView
             didSelectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {

//filePathsofimages  contains 10 image paths
```

// The below code updating image if am loading the uiviewcontroller and clicking the thumbnails  instead of opening another viewcontroller and coming back then clicking..

```
     img =[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[filePathsofImages objectAtIndex:index]];
                [self setBookImage:img];
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
[book_cover_image setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: just imaging 2 uiviewcontrollers  one is blue and another is red ,blue contains a thumbnail near to uiToolbar and also contain some button .If i click that button i can open red UIviewcontroller. If i do like that and come back then click thumbnail then its not updating new humbanil images

Comment: first tym its working ,but if i go some other viewcontroller and came back then its not working ,.and your code fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the content of your var img when you back??

Maybe that is reseted.

Try NSLog in img var

Comment: Thanks alot tony for your answer , [book_cover_image setNeedsDisplay] is working